# Generating jar from several class-files with maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, building

I am using eclipse with maven. I need to combine several class-files in a jar while building the project with maven.

so i added the following to the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                         <archive>
                            <index>false</index>
                            <classesDirectory>${project.build.classes.de.filter}</classesDirectory>
                            <finalName>BasicFilters</finalName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.Plugins}</outputDirectory>
                          </archive>
                        </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>Building Jar from Filters</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>jar</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The building says: build success, but it does not built any jar and no info from the plugin is displayed in the console.

Comment: run as->maven build->goals: eclipse:eclipse

Comment: that is the default maven goal, this will execute eclipse:generate-project and eclipse:generate-classpath. use mvn package

Comment: ok thanks, now its working
but I have a little problem: it works just with absolute paths
how can I configure relative paths?

if i'm setting: <outputDirectory>${project.target.Plugins}</outputDirectory>
he stores it just in Target not in "Target/Plugins"

and any kind of slash or backslash makes maven interpret it as absolute path -> not even in the target-dir

Comment: use <outputDirectory>target/plugins</outputDirectory>, it should work

Answer (score -1):

Use `mvn package` to create a .jar file provided you have the right configurations. Read this [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_create_a_JAR_and_install_it_in_my_local_repository). Here, you have a good tutorial [link](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/)